JSON Path Syntax using filters
So I was using a JSONPath syntax for the JSON below
{
    "documents": [
        {
            "id": 1231,
            "doctType": "FFS",
            "docValue": "3123123",
            "isPrim": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 1232,
            "docType": "National Identity Card",
            "docValue": "0000840317",
            "isPrim": 1,
            "resources": [
                {
                    "id": 23893452,
                    "name": "national card"
                },
                {
                    "id": 52524055,
                    "name": "national card front"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4266737,
                    "name": "physical Form"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1233,
            "docType": "National Identity 1234",
            "docValue": "312312",
            "isPrim": 1,
            "resources": [
                {
                    "id": 23893452,
                    "name": "national card back"
                },
                {
                    "id": 52524055,
                    "name": "national card front"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4266737,
                    "name": "physicalForm"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}            

Here I use the below mentioned JSONPath
$.documents[?(@.isPrim == 1)]
This returns the below output
[
    {
        "id": 1232,
        "docType": "National Identity Card",
        "docValue": "0000840317",
        "isPrim": 1,
        "resources": [
            {
                "id": 23893452,
                "name": "national card"
            },
            {
                "id": 52524055,
                "name": "national card front"
            },
            {
                "id": 4266737,
                "name": "physical Form"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1233,
        "docType": "National Identity 1234",
        "docValue": "312312",
        "isPrim": 1,
        "resources": [
            {
                "id": 23893452,
                "name": "national card back"
            },
            {
                "id": 52524055,
                "name": "national card front"
            },
            {
                "id": 4266737,
                "name": "physicalForm"
            }
        ]
    }
]

Now I want to get the first JSON in this array or the first element, for that I tried using
$.documents[?(@.isPrim == 1)][0]
but this doesn't work. Please help me understand how can I pick the first element here. I can use any other filter for this. My need is to pick the first element.

This question is similar to: JsonPath - Filter Array and get only the first element. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
